# Flutter - issue with downloading the file and opening it with the default app on ios

Tags: flutter

I have built an app with flutter, what I am trying to do is download a document, these are jpeg, jpg or pdf files, from my REST api, and open it within the app so the user can see it,

The below piece of code is the issue, I am trying to use the openfile package in flutter, the code works perfectly on android, it opens the image automatically, but on ios, it gives the attached screen after attempting to download.

I am putting part of my code which I believe is the issue.

Code to specify the plugin parameter

```
if (Platform.isIOS)
      directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    else
      directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Code to open the file

```
OpenFile.open(downloadPath).then((_result) {
         _closePopup();
          print(_result);
        }).catchError((error) {
          print("Could not open file *** $error");
          FileDownloader.lastError =
              "Could not open file: " + error.toString();
          _closePopup();
        });
    } else {
```

Any guidance on this will help.

[Buttton sample I am trying to work out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL1vs.jpg)
[IOS Behaviour with code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74GoS.jpg)